# Updating a table's cell with an ImageButton in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx

I have a class that initiates a table with 3 cells filled like so:

[leftButton]    [ImageButton]    [rightButton]

---

ImageButton is created & added to characterSelection array:

```
Texture characters2 = TrafficGame.res.getTexture("chevy");
characterImageStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
car = new TextureRegion(characters2, 32, 32);
characterImageStyle.imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(car));
characterImageChevy = new ImageButton(characterImageStyle);
characterSelection.add(characterImageChevy);
```

Adding to table when player selection is initiated:

```
 table.add(characterSelection.pop());
```

Now when the user clicks the left/right button, moveLeft/Right() gets called:

```
public void moveLeft(){
    table.getChildren().get(1).clear();
}
```

This where I'm stuck. It obviously clears the cell but I have no idea how to add an ImageButton back to it from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table doesn't support swapping actors into the same cell. Instead of clearing the image button, you should hide it. When you're ready for it to show another image, change its image and show it.

```
characterImageChevy.hide();

((TextureRegionDrawable)characterImageChevy.getStyle().imageUp).setTexture(...);
characterImageChevy.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation. I was coding as if I had to create an ImageButton for each character when I should have thought of it as just a placeholder for a TextureRegion I suppose.  
`((TextureRegionDrawable)characterImage.getStyle().imageUp).setRegion(characterSelection.peek());`
Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Table supports swapping elements in the same cell, although not directly with a method "swap". But you can get the cell of an Actor, then clear it, and set a new Actor. I wrote a separate answer below to demonstrate it.

Comment: You're right. I was misremembering the fact that you cannot insert cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly change the contents of a Scene2D cell. You can obtain the Cell by asking the table to return Cell for a particular Actor. After that you can clear the Cell and set new Actor for its contents.

```
// first, grab the Actor that you wish to replace
ImageButton actor = characterImageChevy; // you know where to get it from

// next, take the Cell where it's at
Cell<Table> cell = table.getCell(characterImageChevy);

// remove the actor
cell.clearActor();

// set new Actor
cell.setActor(characterImageChevy);
```

Comment: I just found I use table.cells.get(index) to get Cell<Actor> which can't use in setActor as parameter. I need to cast it to Cell<Table>.